# system.applicationHost and system.WebServer only for AppPool?

Tags: asp.net, iis

There are various requests limits parameters available in system.applicationHost and system.WebServer app host config sections which I would like to set for a single app or app pool.

**Is it possible to include system.applicationHost and system.WebServer sections in a application web.config and have them work only for that app or app pool(assuming it's the only app in that pool)?**  Or will these sections be ignored when in a web.config?

Comment: Impossible in `web.config` and give it up.

Comment: system.webServer is definitely allowed, but only some child elements.  Some elements have `overrideModeDefault='Deny'` in applicationHost, such as the security child element, which means it is ignored.  Certainly some settings only affect the application, such as system.webServer/handlers, but others sound like they affect the server.  That's likely why they are set to `overrideModeDefault='Deny'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't attempt to check security related settings in `web.config`, as they can easily be modified by someone who has no idea what security impact a change can lead to. Restrict changes to `applicationHost.config` and then only administrators can touch it.

Second, IIS configuration system uses `section` tag in `applicationHost.config` to lock down overriding. So if a section has `overrideModeDefault` set to `Deny`, then you only only set its settings in `applicationHost.config`.

Third, even within `applicationHost.config`, you are restricted by another section setting called `allowDefinition`, whose value further restricts where in that file you can set a value. `AppHostOnly` means the section is at server level, and cannot be set at site/app level. `MachineToApplication` looses the check, so you can override via location tags at site/app level.

By reviewing the default settings in your `applicationHost.config` you can easily see what Microsoft decided.

> Don't attempt to fool the system by manually editing those section definitions, as back in IIS binaries, some restrictions are hard coded.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that server administrators understand HTTP security settings better than senior app developers. In my experience, any settings that require a solid understanding of the HTTP model and how requests are handled will be misunderstood by server administrators.  Certainly even some devs misunderstand, but senior devs in charge of deployments and final review of config settings should know what they're doing.  **Otherwise solid answer.**